# One class property (of many) is lost after object passed back to caller/creator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, constructor

I have a class that includes two constructors.

One constructor `File_Attachment(int Attachment_ID)` creates an instance of the class, populated with data from a single database row.

The second constructor `File_Attachment(string type, int mid)` creates numerous instances of the class with the first constructor, and collects them in a List<>.

Here is the full class code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public class File_Attachment {

    private string cs = ApplicationData.dbConnectionString;
    private string where = "";

    public List<File_Attachment> File_Attachments = new List<File_Attachment>();

    public int Attachment_ID { get; set; }
    public string Attachment_Type { get; set; }
    public int Attachment_Type_ID { get; set; }
    public int Old_ID { get; set; }
    public string File_Name { get; set; }
    public string Content_Type { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }

    // ****************************************************************************************************************************

    public File_Attachment() {
    }


    // ****************************************************************************************************************************

    public File_Attachment(int Attachment_ID) {

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs)) {

            cn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM File_Attachments WHERE Attachment_ID = " + Attachment_ID, cn))
            using (SqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

                if (rs.HasRows) {

                    rs.Read();

                    Attachment_ID = (int) rs["Attachment_ID"];
                    Attachment_Type = (string) rs["Attachment_Type"];
                    Attachment_Type_ID = (int) rs["Attachment_Type_ID"];
                    Old_ID = (int) rs["Old_ID"];
                    File_Name = (string) rs["File_Name"];
                    Content_Type = (string) rs["Content_Type"];
                    Data = (byte[]) rs["Data"];

                }
            }
        }

    }

    // ****************************************************************************************************************************

    public File_Attachment(string type, int mid) {

        if (type.ToLower() == "meeting") {
            where = " Attachment_Type = 'Meeting' ";
        }
        if (type.ToLower() == "discussion") {
            where = " Attachment_Type = 'Discussion' ";
        }
        if (type.ToLower() == "action") {
            where = " Attachment_Type = 'Action' ";
        }

        where += " AND Attachment_Type_ID = " + mid.ToString() + " ";

        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cs)) {

            cn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM File_Attachments WHERE " + where, cn))
            using (SqlDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {

                if (rs.HasRows) {

                    while (rs.Read()) {

                        File_Attachment fa = new File_Attachment((int)rs["Attachment_ID"]);
                        File_Attachments.Add(fa);

                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }

}
```

The problem is, the second class constructor creates numerous instances of itself (same class) using the first constructor.

During debugging, at the conclusion of the first contructor's code:

```
if (rs.HasRows) {

                    rs.Read();

                    Attachment_ID = (int) rs["Attachment_ID"];
                    Attachment_Type = (string) rs["Attachment_Type"];
                    Attachment_Type_ID = (int) rs["Attachment_Type_ID"];
                    Old_ID = (int) rs["Old_ID"];
                    File_Name = (string) rs["File_Name"];
                    Content_Type = (string) rs["Content_Type"];
                    Data = (byte[]) rs["Data"];  //<--------- BREAK POINT!!!!


                }
```

... All the fields, including Attachment_ID are populated with correct data.

However, when the List<> object is received back, each instance in the list has all the fields **STILL** properly populated with data **EXCEPT** Attachment_ID, which are ALL zero.

See debugger screen caps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sV1Rw.jpg

It is perplexing, because each object in the List<> has Attachment_Type_ID with proper data, even though it is an (int) field just like Attachment_ID is.  See pics, again.

Things I have considered:

Originally, in my visual studio project, Attachment_ID was declared:

```
public int Attachment_ID { get; private set; }
```

This was later changed to:

```
public int Attachment_ID { get; set; }
```

Is this a caching issue?  I've rebuilt the solution several times.  No change.

Also, In the database, Attachment_ID is the Primary Key, if that helps.

What is happening to my Attachment_ID in between the time that it is added to the list, and the time the list is received back by the caller/initiator code?

Comment: is there any chance your constructor has a *local* called `Attachment_ID` ? i.e. if you F2 on `Attachment_ID` - does it take you where you expect?

Comment: you should not use a constructor that will return a list of instance of a class (where the constructor is inside in that class). move the logic to create a list of object into other class or function in the same class.

Comment: If you followed proper casing/naming conventions you wouldn't have these types of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem you have is that you declared a global variable with the exact name as a local variable. That's problematic, because it leads to weird issues.

Try replacing:

```
public File_Attachment(int Attachment_ID)
```

with:

```
public File_Attachment(int attachmentID)
```

Then in your first constructor, change:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM File_Attachments WHERE Attachment_ID = " + Attachment_ID, cn))
```

to:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM File_Attachments WHERE Attachment_ID = " + attachmentID, cn))
```

It's likely that when you do:

```
Attachment_ID = (int) rs["Attachment_ID"];
```

You're changing the **Local Variable** to that value, which gets thrown away when the constructor is done.

As a bonus, your first constructor should simply set the "Attachment_ID" to the parameter it takes. You don't need to set the ID to the one you find in the database, because your constructor gets the ID as a parameter.

So something like:

```
public File_Attachment(int attachmentID){
    Attachment_ID = attachmentID;
    ...
```

Comment: OMG.... I could have looked at that for a WEEK and never seen that.  Thanks!  That was exactly the problem and it did solve the problem.  Looks like I'll start my week off on a productive note!

Comment: This is a good example of why proper naming can go a long way. Also, marking an answer as correct will help others who stumble upon this question, even if this case is pretty specific.

Comment: By the way, here's a reference for C# naming conventions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions

Comment: Thanks, Clay.  I was going to mark this as an answer, but SO won't let me until a certain amount of time has passed.  And, THANKS for the naming convention point-out.  I've been wondering about that for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Revisiting this a year and a half later, I learned later a different approach that I like better.

Since the class has an Attachment_ID field, and one of it's constructors has an Attachment_ID argument, if you want to refer to the constructor argument, leave it "Attachment_ID".  If you want to refer to the Class field/variable, preface it with the "this" keyword.

So, `Attachment_ID` refers to the constructor argument.

And, `this.Attachment_ID` refer to the class field/variable.

Comment: that's not a good idea. having a method parameter with same name as a member variable is so prone to error. Yes, you can use the `this.` idiom to distinguish the two but there is no need to put yourself in this situation when you can simply use a different (and largely used) naming convention for method parameters.

Comment: What is this new learning you speak of?  ;-)  Is there a standard, or something you can point me to?  And, thanks!

Comment: The link given by @clay07g oin a comment for another answer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions